# Performance issue when loading a big file into a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, .net

The Notepad opens a text file (with 20,000 lines) in a second but when I use `richtextbox1.LoadFile()` or `File.ReadAllText()` it takes some minutes to load file! what's wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] of your testing code?

Comment: As I know notepad can load file in stream (for example open 1gb file, but load it it asynchronous), and what you see is just a first small fraction of file. It can still load it for a few minutes. How you measured performance?

Comment: If you use `File.ReadAllLines`, how long does that take? I doubt that long. That would kinda be what notepad does. Perhaps because you're reading each line and processing is what is slow. Plus notepad may use paging internally who knows.

Comment: "_Why is there no way ...?_" Why are you so certain that there is no such way in .NET? Hint: Notepad uses what is called memory-mapped files. .NET also supports opening a file as a memory-mapped file...

Comment: Using `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`, I was able to both create a 20000 line file and read it entirely in less than 0.5 seconds.  If it is taking minutes for you, then the problem is likely the method you are using to read the file.  Please share some code.

Comment: Please take a breather to edit the question before bombing with your downvotes 

Comment: Note that your problem is not with reading the text file, your code comments in your code example even confirm that you know that. You should therefore really rename the misleading title and write a description relating to your actual problem. Your problem clearly is not related to reading a text file, but with populating a richtextbox, as your code comments also rather clearly acknowledge.

Comment: *Much* better title/description. Downvote retracted!

Comment: What if not trying read the text files as lines and then join the lines back together to form the content of the text file again? Instead, try to read the whole text file content as a single string (File.ReadAllText) and assign this string to the richtextbox? This eliminates string.join, which should speed up things a bit, hopefully...

Comment: I stand corrected...in my testing, using `ReadLines` into a list of predefined size of `20000` plus `string.Join` was actually 10% faster than `ReadAllText`. That being said, the setting of the `Text` property in both cases was completed in less than 200 milliseconds.

Comment: @RufusL, that's a curious finding. Which of the tests did you do first? (Not that the file being cached for the 2nd test is spoiling your results...)

Comment: @elgonzo I undeleted my answer and added the test app I used. Would love to hear if I missed something obvious! :)

Comment: @RufusL, Using your unaltered code, the ReadAllText test is (a little) faster. See here: https://imgur.com/a/ESUt7gK. The image shows the debug output of two runs. In each run i executed each test 4 times in alternating fashion invoked by button clicks. In one test, i started with the ReadAllText test, in the other test i started with ReadAllLines+String.Join. (I used a USB3.0 external HDD as test storage medium). I have no idea why for you ReadAllLines+String.Join would turn out to be faster, especially considering that more work is done in this test compared to the ReadAllText test. Hmm...

Comment: I've updated my question. I don't think it's still off-topic.

Comment: I finally understand the problem. The issue was not with my code, it was with RichTextBox itself. This control is very slower than Multi line TextBox in loading big files. **I used multi line TextBox and file was loaded in 3 seconds.** Unfortunately This good question was closed, devoted and tagged "off-topic" without any reasons by professional developers.

Comment: Please delete this question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reading the file into an array and then going back over that array and joining each item into a single string, just read the entire file contents into the `Text` property using the `ReadAllText` method, which returns a string that represents the contents of the text file:

```
richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

However, the results were mixed. Both methods performed similarly, with `ReadLines` + `string.Join` taking less time more often than not.

Here is my test application:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private const string FilePath = @"f:\private\temp\temp.txt";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Create a file with 20,000 lines
        var fileLines = new List<string>(20000);

        for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
        {
            fileLines.Add($"This is line number {i + 1}.");
        }

        File.WriteAllLines(FilePath, fileLines);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Test loading with ReadAllText
        richTextBox1.Text = string.Empty;

        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(FilePath);
        sw.Stop();

        Debug.WriteLine("ReadAllText = " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Test loading with ReadLines and string.Join
        richTextBox1.Text = string.Empty;

        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        lines.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(FilePath));         
        richTextBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);
        sw.Stop();

        Debug.WriteLine("ReadLines + string.Join = " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

Results when executing `ReadAllText` first (times in milliseconds)

```
ReadAllText = 157
ReadLines + string.Join = 143
```

Results when executing `ReadLines` first (times in milliseconds)

```
ReadLines + string.Join = 160
ReadAllText = 152
```

Comment: Have an upvote for trying to answer a `question that does not appear to be about programming` ...

Comment: I just noticed that the app after running is disabled by UAC in the Task manager.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ thanks, but how is filling a `RichTextBox` from a `file` not about programming?

Comment: Frankly that's just the consensus that 3 other members voted for, honestly it's too broad/opinionated answers and is subjective IMHO. Do you find this question to be constructive?

Comment: @RufusL because I think It's not rocket science 

Comment: @kokabi In my tests, it's 10% faster. I'll add the code...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ There are 2 votes to close because there is not a complete example that reproduces the problem, and 1 vote to close because it's a "typographical error" (which I don't get). Doesn't mean it's not about programming... :)

Comment: Again, that was the *general* message for closing this question as I explained in my comment.

Comment: Thank you @RufusL for answering but I've not yet got an answer to my question. I've updated my question. have you tested your code with a big text file?

Comment: Well the sample above creates a 20000 line text file and is able to load it into the rtb in less than 200 milliseconds. What size is your sample file?

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading from an Rtf file you should try letting the control do the work. This is an excerpt from Microsoft's documentations on the control, found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox?view=netframework-4.7.2.

```
public void CreateMyRichTextBox()
{
    RichTextBox richTextBox1 = new RichTextBox();
    richTextBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;


    richTextBox1.LoadFile("C:\\MyDocument.rtf");
    richTextBox1.Find("Text", RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase);

    richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Verdana", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;

    richTextBox1.SaveFile("C:\\MyDocument.rtf", RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);

    this.Controls.Add(richTextBox1);
}
```

If this does not improve performance you may need to look at asynchronously loading the data through the Lines property (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines?view=netframework-4.7.2).